# How can I get the value of a hyperlink in Visual Basic 2013 as a DataSet

Tags: database, excel, vba, xls

I have an Excel-based database. In that there is a column with hyperlinks (each row contains more than 1 hyperlinks). I would like to put these into a Visual Basic 2013 DataSet object. My problem is, that only the name of the hyperlink is shown, instead of the link.

Is it possible to get the link instead of its name from the loaded DataSet object? Or should I write a function which reads each rows from the database and converts the hyperlinks into normal links?

To create the database (14000 x 13) it needs approximately 30 minutes.

Here is the code that I use:

For k = 2 To theRange.UsedRange.Rows.Count

```
        Dim Rw As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        Rw("T1") = theRange.Cells(k, 1).value
        Rw("t2") = theRange.Cells(k, 2).value
        Rw("t3") = theRange.Cells(k, 3).value
        Rw("t4") = theRange.Cells(k, 4).value
        Rw("t5") = theRange.Cells(k, 5).value
        Rw("t6") = theRange.Cells(k, 6).value
        Rw("t7") = theRange.Cells(k, 7).value

      Dim rg = theRange.Cells(k, 6)
        If theRange.Cells(k, 6).value <> "" Then
            Rw("link1") = (rg.Hyperlinks(1).Address)
        End If

        Dim rg1 = theRange.Cells(k, 13)
        If theRange.Cells(k, 13).value <> "" Then
            Rw("link2k") = (rg1.Hyperlinks(1).Address)
        End If
        dt.Rows.Add(Rw)
    Next
```

PS: With the the excel.range function the same happens.

Comment: That is very strange because your code works for me. This is especially the cause because you're referencing the hyperlink's address and **not** the `rg.Hyperlinks(1).Name` (which should contain the name of the link showing in Excel instead of the link address). The only possible alternative I can think of is looking into the `rg.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress` (which is normally reserved for links within Excel files). I assume that you are not using the `=Hyperlink()` function to store the addresses, right?

Comment: agreed with Raph. you specify rightly `hyperlink.address`, so this is strange